# WinEdt 10.2 How to activate the active filename indicator?

Tags: winedt

I've just switched computer and installed WinEdt 10.2 on the new machine (which uses Windows 10 Pro). I find I've lost the one-line horizontal window that previously appeared between the toolbars and the text and showed the names of all the .tex files that are open at any one time. How to get it back?

Comment: one-line? You are good, I never manage this, my document tabs take always more than one line ;-)

Comment: Any feedback on the answer below?....

Answer (score 1):

From the "View" menu, select "Document Tabs".

[image]

This should solve your issue.